What is AASAservice known as com.samsung.aasaservice on Samsung phones
On Samsung devices there's a /system/app/AASAservice/AASAservice.apk with app id com.samsung.aasaservice. It seems to be tied to ASKS Security Software via  AASA_ASKSManager.
What is it for?
One bit of information was posted on reddit:

This is an application for updating terminal security policies.

Update existing security policies to suit the latest security
technologies and issues.
This app is designed to reduce security risks and keep information
safe

(Pulled from app description, translated from Korean).

Apparently something as Samsung's equivalent to Android Device Policy.
What is the origial app description in Korean? Are there official Samsung docs, maybe in Korean?
Can it be safely disabled if not using Samsung services?

Some (all) details explained in the following link but not in Korean: https://androidsrc.net/com-samsung-aasaservice/
